# Create subset of data frame in R of multiple dummy variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) that contains many variables, including dummy variables, black (coded 0,1), race (coded 1,2,3,4), and male(coded 0,1).

I'd like to create a subset of the dataframe with only black=1, race=4, and male=1.

I've tried

```
subset_df<- subset(df, black==1 | race==4 |male==1, select=c(black, race, male))
```

and I end up with a new dataframe with my 3 variables, but the observations are not correct.
I've also tried

```
subset_df<- subset(df, black==1 & race==4 & male==1, select=c(black, race, male))
```

and get an empty dataframe for my 3 variables.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` so that it can b tested.  Your second code seems to be correct

Comment: Also, check the `str(df)`.  If you have columns that are `character` class and your values are `'01'` `'04'` etc, then this will not match  and results in empty dataframe as subset

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

you can always use dplyr for this:

library(dplyr)

```
subset_df <- df %>%
    filter(black == 1, race == 4, male == 1)
```